# How can I save a bunch of variables when someone leaves the tab?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game, and I want to make it so that when you close the tab its saves. The game is like when you click a button, it updates a variable, but I don't know how to save that variable. It is a numeric value, but I'm unsure whether or not localStorage works with that, but I've used it and it seems to just use strings.
I have this variable, but don't know how to save it.

```
var clickvalue = 0 // the variable for the clicks
```

So there's a button, and you click it, the value goes up. But when you close the tab, all the data is gone and you have to restart. Is there a way that I can save this?

I used localStorage, but it just thought it was a string.

Comment: localStorage is just a string, but you can turn most things into a (JSON) string.

Comment: Use `visibilitychange` instead of `unload` or `beforeunload`, as the latter 2 are specifically marked as "unreliable" events: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/

Comment: You may want to consider how long you want the data you save to persist and be recoverable. The indexedDB API may be a good option but has a bit of a learning curve relative to local storage. And, also equally important, is that you may not want to rely upon any event related to closing a tab to save all the data at once, but can be saving the data with each event that changes it--whether mouse events or text input events, etcetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that [localStorage data is always converted to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#:%7E:text=The%20keys%20and%20the%20values%20are%20always%20strings). But you can always convert that string back to a number if you need to:

```
var clickvalue = 0;

//Store the click value (automatically converts to a string)
localStorage.setItem('clicks', clickvalue);

//Retrieve the click value (must manually convert back to a number)
clickvalue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
```

If you want to store multiple values as your title suggests, you can either store them all individually as I did above, using different names for each value, or you can store them together in an object. Remember that you'll have to convert the object to and from a string too, like this:

```
var values = {
    clickvalue: 0,
    username: "max",
    favoriteFruit: "bananas"
};

//Store the values
localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values));

//Retrieve the values
values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides `localStorage`, you can use the `IndexedDB`, which won't block the UI.

Here's a [simple library](https://github.com/uxtely/js-utils/tree/main/indexed-db) (I think it's the simplest one). Usage (a "File" is a plain JS object):

```js
const dbName = () => 'the-user-id'

idbSaveFile({ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }).catch(console.error)

idbReadFile(1) // fileId = 1
  .then(data => { console.log(data) })
  .catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on localStorage, you can define 2 useful methods like below, be care to handle the boundary scenario like the value is `undefined`

```
const persistItem = (key, val) => {
  if (val === undefined) {
    console.warn(
      `Trying to set undefined to ${key}, convert undefined to null instead`,
    );
    val = null;
  }
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
};

export const getPersistedItem = (key) => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
};
```